# please how do I add new key - value pairs to a dictionary without overriding the existing key?

Tags: python, django, django-views

please how do I add new key - value pairs to a dictionary without overriding the existing key?

I’m building a project requires users to give an answer that I will use as a key and value pair.

Everything is working well but if a user make a mistake and enter a key that already exists, it will override the existing one.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to add the code you are using. Code is always clearer than descriptions.

Comment: What do you want to do in the event of a collision?  Do you want to reject the new entry (in which case you could just `assert key not in dictionary` before adding it) or do you want to provide a way for them to roll back the change (in which case you might want to keep a list of values rather than a single value)?

Comment: Check what dict offers: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Then choose what is best for your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an if statement as a guard to it:

```
# Instead of doing this to add a value
my_dict[new_key] = new_value

# Guard it with an if statement
if new_key not in my_dict:
  my_dict[new_key] = new_value
```